# When Binding a GridView to a DataTable, How can we Change the value displayed by a BoundField

Tags: gridview, datatable, bind, boundfield

When Binding a GridView to a DataTable, How can we Change the value displayed by a BoundField

Comment: Found it!
must use RowDataBound event Handler and then check the RowType ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is like so:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
Checked='<%# (((String)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status")) == "O")?true:false %>' />
```

and then you have control in the code behind like:

```
protected void gvFiles_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "LastUser").ToString() == "x")
        {
            TextBox txtId = gvFiles.FindControl("txtId") as TextBox;
            txtId.Text = "NA";
        }
    }

}
```